# expected { Object () } not to be empty - WebdriverIO - POM - Chai

Tags: javascript, chai, assert, webdriver-io

I am currently using WebdriverIO with POM and Chai expect/asserts.
I have not been able to get my chai assert to work.

```
expectChai(watchesPage.infoTitle).to.not.be.empty;
```

When I run the test, I get an error in my console log saying `expected { Object () } not to be empty`.

This is my JS spec file.

```
//chai.pom.js

import watchesPage from "../ebay/watches.page";
const expectChai = require("chai").expect;
const assert = require("chai").assert;

describe("Watches Page", () => {
  it("should show the banner container", async () => {
    browser.url("https://www.ebay.com/b/Watches/260325/bn_7117208191");
    const watchesText = $(".title-banner__title");
    await expect(watchesText).toBeDisplayed();
  });

  it("should show the banner title", async () => {
    //const infoTitle = await $(".title-banner__subtitle");
    await watchesPage.infoTitle.getText();

    //const infoTitleText = await infoTitle.getText();
    await expect(watchesPage.infoTitle).toHaveTextContaining(
      "The place to elevate your style since 1995.."
    );

    expectChai(watchesPage.infoTitle).to.not.be.empty;
    assert.isEmpty(watchesPage.infoTitle);
  });
});
```

And this is my page file. please ignore the constructor called super.

```
//watches.page.js
import Page from "./page";

class WatchesPage extends Page {
  //const infoTitle = await $(".title-banner__subtitle");
  //const infoTitleText = await infoTitle.getText();
  get infoTitle() {
    return $(".title-banner__subtitle");
  }

  open() {
    super.open("htpp:");
  }
}

export default new WatchesPage();
```

I hope you can help me, thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Hey! could you tell me what version of nodejs are you on?

Comment: Hello, this is my nodejs version
v14.17.0